# Why can't I use model methods as defaults? What is self in Python/Django models anyway?

Tags: python, django, class, model, self

I have a very basic problem in understanding the behaviour of `self`.

Specifically, I don't understand why neither of the following two snippets of code work, the first one causing the interpreter to complain that

> `self` is missing as an argument,

the second that

> `self` couldn't be referenced.

```
class Model(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auto_gen_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=gen_field())

    def gen_field(self):
        return self.name + 'something'
```

---

```
class Model(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auto_gen_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=gen_field(self))

    def gen_field(self):
        return self.name + 'something'
```

The following code, which uses `self` as well, works fine:

```
class Model(models.Model)
    name = models.CHarField(max_length=200)
    auto_gen_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def gen_field(self):
        return self.name + 'something'

    def save(self):
        self.auto_gen_field = self.gen_field()
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Why does the `self` reference exists in one place but not in the other?

How do I fix the first two snippets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're invoking the method at the time when the field is declared. At that point there is no `self`.

You don't want to do that anyway. Quite apart from any problems with self, doing so would return a static value for the default, so all instances would use the same value. That is why it is important to pass the **callable**: `gen_field` - not the result - `gen_field()`.

(Note however that still won't work: the instance wouldn't be passed to the function because it's not being invoked as a method on an instance. Overriding save is the way to go.)

Answer (score 3):

`self` is *by convention* (it is really a name like any other, what matters is that it is the *first argument* of your class methods) a *reference to the current instance of the class*,  more or less like `this` in C++/Java.

Now, in

```
class Model(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    auto_gen_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=gen_field())
```

When `models.CharField(max_length=200, default=gen_field())` is evaluated there is *no instance* of the class, so you can't add a `self` in there.
It doesn't and can't possibly make sense.

Now, from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default

> Field.default¶
>
> The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable
>   object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is
>   created.
>
> The default cannot be a mutable object (model instance, list, set,
>   etc.), as a reference to the same instance of that object would be
>   used as the default value in all new model instances. Instead, wrap
>   the desired default in a callable.

You want to pass a `callable` - which basically is akin to a [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).

What *would* work is:

```
def some_function():
     return something

...

auto_gen_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=some_function)
```

You can **not**, however, use a model method like `gen_field()` as `default` because Django does *not* pass a model instance as the first argument of the provided callable.

You have to override `save`.